# I'm getting a typeError: string indices must be integers, not type

Tags: python, typeerror

```
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key = "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV" 

def encode():
    alpha[""] = key["x"]

def decode():
    key[""] = alpha[""] 

def menu():
    response = raw_input("""Crypto Menu
        quit(0)
        encode(1)
        decode(2)""")
    return response

def main():   
    keepGoing = True
    while keepGoing:
    response = menu()
    if response == "1":
        plain = raw_input("text to be encoded: ")
        print encode()
    elif response == "2":
        coded = raw_input("code to be decyphered: ")
        print decode()
    elif response == "0":
        print "Thanks for doing secret spy stuff with me."
        keepGoing = False
    else:
        print "I don't know what you want to do..."

print main()
```

I keep getting a TypeError saying string indices must be integers, not type. Not sure how to correct this, it is highlighting the decode and encode variables.

Comment: sorry first time posting on here, so formatting is still looking pretty bad

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow, you should always use the programming language you are operating with as a tag. People tend to look for questions with certain tags and your post is more likely to be seen and answered if you specify your tags properly.

Comment: Read the stack trace, figure out which line is raising the error, and include that in your question if you still can't figure out the problem.

Comment: it is raising the error on line 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going on here, but you're definitely having issues with your `encode` and `decode` functions. If I understand what you're trying to do, you could rewrite them as follows:

```
def encode(string):
    alpha = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    key = 'XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV'
    encoded = []
    for character in string:
        character_index = alpha.index(character)
        encoded.append(key[character_index])
    return ''.join(encoded)

def decode(string):
    alpha = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    key = 'XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV'
    decoded = []
    for character in string:
        character_index = key.index(character)
        decoded.append(alpha[character_index])
    return ''.join(decoded)
```

Each function is doing essentially the same thing (here's what `encode` is doing:

1. Creating an empty list called encoded. I'll use this to store each character, translated, in order.
2. Loop through the characters of the string passed in.
3. At each iteration, find its index in the string `alpha`.
4. Find the character in `key` at that same index and append that character to the list `encoded`
5. Once all the characters have been translated, join them into a string and return that string.

Note: This will fail if a character in the `string` argument is not found in the `alpha` string. You could add some error checking.

You could make this even more general if you wanted to allow for different keys. You could write a `translate` function like this:

```
def translate(string, from_language_string, to_language_string):
    translated = []
    for character in string:
        character_index = from_language_string.index(character)
        translated.append(to_language_string[character_index])
    return ''.join(translated)
```

And then your `encode` and `decode` functions could be written like this:

```
def encode(string):
    return translate(string, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV')

def decode(string):
    return translate(string, 'XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
```

To address what's going on in the rest of your code, for the conditionals in your `main` function, you'll just want to make sure to pass the strings read in from `raw_input` to the `encode` and `decode` functions as needed. Something like this:

```
if response == '1':
    plain = raw_input('text to be encoded: ')
    print encode(plain)
    # and so on
```

Good luck.

Comment: its definitely coming together but, ive not used the character_index = alpha.index(character) part before so it comes back as substring not found and im not sure why. any chance to explain that a bit more maybe?

Comment: Can you show me the context where that's coming up? Basically, it means that `character` isn't found in `alpha`. Could be because it's lowercase or something. Without seeing it, that would be my guess.

Comment: Sure, when i go to run the program it allows me to choose whether to encode or decode and so i chose option 1(encode). I type the word to be encoded, trouble, and that is when it comes back with an error on line 6 of your section you displayed. it says ValueError substring not found

Comment: Yeah. Since "trouble" is lowercase, it's not finding them in the alpha string.

Comment: ok so would i just added .uppercase to the raw_input line within the menu?

Comment: The method in Python is `.upper()`

Comment: alright so i put the upper right after raw_input....so it looks like this raw_input.upper("""Crypto Menu etc.) says the function object has no attribute 'upper'. did i just put it in the wrong spot?

Comment: Yeah. You could do `plain = raw_input("Text to be encoded: ").upper()`

Comment: I have one more thing to finish up on it, but i want to see if i can solve it myself

Comment: Excellent. Good luck. I would appreciate if you accept the answer if you feel it answered your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key = "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV" 

def encode():
    alpha[""] = key["x"]

def decode():
    key[""] = alpha[""]
```

I think you misunderstand how indexing in strings works. So let me try to correct this:

Take a string, like `x = "hello"`. The reference `x["h"]` is meaningless. There's no way for Python to interpret this. On the other hand, `x[0]` is meaningful. It returns the element of `x` at index `0`. That's `"h"`, in our case.

Similarly, `alpha[""]` doesn't mean anything. When you use the square brackets, you are trying to specify an **index** in the string `alpha`. But the indices of `alpha` are integers. `alpha[0]` returns `"A"`. `alpha[1]` returns "`B`". `alpha[25]` returns "`Z`".

So you need to use integers for your indices. Notation like `key["x"]` doesn't mean anything, and that raises errors.

Comment: That is definitely making it more understandable for me, however I am still unclear as to what should be put into the square brackets. the idea of the program is to ask the user whether they want to encode or decode a set of letters. the program will then use the alpha variable and transfer then into the key variable, and vice versa. so should i just simply put alpha[0] = key[0] and the opposite for the decode variable? will this tell the computer that each letter represents the letter in the same position for the two variable strings?(alpha and key)